# Method for selecting unique resistor values in all combinations

Tags: resistors, switches, relay, control-system

I do controls, and sometimes I want to monitor more dry contacts than I have digital inputs for.  I'm cheap, and don't want to pay for more points, so sometimes I'll put some resistors in parallel with the contacts, and put the (resistor||contact) pairs in series, and read them using an RTD input.  With three contacts, it's easy to pick three resistor values that give me 8 unique combinations within a comfortable range and with comfortable distance in between.  Say 10k, 7.5k, and 15k.  Moving on up to six contacts, I've now got 64 states, and picking 6 resistances from the E12 series that can satisfy 64 states may not even be possible.

Is there a succinct way to solve this problem of picking x resistances from a standard series, sticking within one decade?  Something I can stick into Excel? 
 Maybe it's very obvious once I restate the problem mathematically in terms of sets or combinatorics, but I worked hard in those classes once so I'd never have to do it again.

Electrically there are obviously many ways to convert a six bit digital value to an analog value, including using resistors and more decades, but anything more complex than single resistors pretty much moves me into "buying a pre-built" solution territory.

Comment: Something like an R 2R ladder making a kind of DAC might work.  But that's just off the top of my head, I haven't had time to work out the details.

Comment: DAC's usually use dual voltages or currents or SPDT switches.  , Can you choose 0.5% R values in binary R sequence to make a DAC with 6 SPST switches? with 1,2,4,8,16,32 [kOhm] to 0V and 64k to 5.00V using an 8 bit ADC?

Comment: Try looking up "R-2R ladder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 8 bit ADC , you can easily gang 6 switches in a binary R ratios.

ADC's normally use SPDT or dual voltages or currents.  But you have SPST contacts.

Rather than E10 values which have only 10% tolerance, you can choose the nearest 0.5% values of; 1k,2k,4k,8k,16k,32k

[Proof of concept](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Aw%20208%20128%20208%20192%200%0Aw%20320%20208%20320%20128%200%0Ar%20208%20128%20320%20128%200%20500%0Aw%20208%20192%20176%20192%200%0Aw%20176%20192%20176%20160%200%0Ar%20176%20160%20112%20160%200%202000%0Ar%20112%20224%20176%20224%200%204000%0Aw%20176%20160%20176%2096%200%0Ar%20112%20288%20176%20288%200%208000%0Ar%20112%2096%20176%2096%200%201000%0Aa%20208%20208%20320%20208%208%2015%20-15%201000000%200%200%20100000%0AO%20320%20128%20368%20128%201%0Aw%20176%20288%20176%20224%200%0Aw%20176%20224%20176%20192%200%0Aw%2064%2096%20112%2096%200%0As%2064%2096%2080%20128%200%201%20false%0As%2064%20160%2080%20192%200%201%20false%0As%2064%20224%2080%20256%200%201%20false%0As%2064%20288%2080%20320%200%201%20false%0Aw%2080%20128%2080%20192%200%0Aw%2080%20192%2080%20256%200%0Aw%2080%20256%2080%20320%200%0Aw%2064%20160%20112%20160%200%0Aw%2064%20288%20112%20288%200%0Aw%2064%20224%20112%20224%200%0AR%2080%20128%2048%20128%200%200%2040%20-5%200%200%200.5%0Aw%2064%20352%20112%20352%200%0Aw%2064%20416%20112%20416%200%0Aw%2080%20384%2080%20448%200%0Aw%2080%20320%2080%20384%200%0As%2064%20416%2080%20448%200%201%20false%0As%2064%20352%2080%20384%200%201%20false%0Aw%20176%20352%20176%20288%200%0Aw%20176%20416%20176%20352%200%0Ar%20112%20416%20176%20416%200%2032000%0Ar%20112%20352%20176%20352%200%2016000%0AR%20208%20224%20208%20256%200%200%2040%200%200%200%200.5%0A)